# Update entire column from another table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two Tables, table 1

[image: Table1]

and table 2

[image: Table 2].

I am trying to copy the column `rawQty` from table 2 to table 1, but it copies only the first row of the table, duplicating the same item in the row.

I have tried with two queries, but both give the same result. Here is my code:

```
public void copyItemToReset(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = MmpDBHelper.this.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql1 = "UPDATE " + ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE + " SET " +ITEMDETAIL_RAWQTY + "= ( "  + " SELECT " + ITEM_REFRESH_RAWQTY + " FROM " + ITEM_REFRESH_TABLE+") WHERE EXISTS " +
        "( SELECT * FROM " + ITEM_REFRESH_TABLE + " WHERE " +ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+ITEMDETAIL_BOMNO + "="+ITEM_REFRESH_TABLE+ "." +ITEM_REFRESH_BOMNO+")";
        String sql2 = "UPDATE " + ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE + " SET " +ITEMDETAIL_FINIQTY + "= ( "  +" SELECT " + ITEM_REFRESH_FINIQTY + " FROM " + ITEM_REFRESH_TABLE+")";
        String sql3 = "UPDATE " + ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE + " SET " +ITEMDETAIL_QTYUMUSED + "= ( "  +" SELECT " + ITEM_REFRESH_QTYUMUSED + " FROM " + ITEM_REFRESH_TABLE+")";

    try {  
        Log.i("sql1=", sql1);
        Log.i("sql2=", sql2);
        Log.i("sql3=", sql3);

        db.execSQL(sql1);
        db.execSQL(sql2);
        db.execSQL(sql3);
    } catch (Exception exe) {
        exe.printStackTrace();
        db.endTransaction();
        Log.e("Insertion failed", "Transaction failure when inserting itemdet data.");
        this.closeDatabase();
        Log.i("DB closed", "Database closed successfully and Copied Successfully");
        errCode = "Err-DB-06";
        LogFileCreator.appendLog(errCode + " : " + exe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `WHERE EXISTS`? Can you not do `WHERE ITEMDETAIL_BOMNO = ITEM_REFRESH_BOMNO`?

Comment: The first command includes too many queries. One SELECT is enough. Like the next 2 commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery must be a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) that returns only one value, but a different one for each execution:

```
UPDATE ItemDetail
SET rawQty = (SELECT rawQty
              FROM ItemRefresh
              WHERE bomNo = ItemDetail.bomNo
                AND item  = ItemDetail.item);
```

Comment: This also giving the same duplication

Comment: Because `bomNo` alone was not unique. Without more information from you, I have to guess what the actual keys are.

Comment: You have to use those field(s) that allow you to uniquely identify the matching row.